# Curl ftp upload files permission

Tags: linux, curl, ftp, server

I trying upload some files to another server in my local network.

```
curl -v -T filename ftp://192.168.1.17//home/ --user user:mypass
```

Login parameters, path and addresss are correct. I've recived

```
< 220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
> USER user
< 331 Please specify the password.
> PASS mypass
< 230 Login successful.
> PWD
< 257 "/home/"
* Entry path is '/home/'
> CWD /
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 250 Directory successfully changed.
> CWD home
< 250 Directory successfully changed.
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
< 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||64962|).
*   Trying 192.168.1.17...
* Connecting to 192.168.1.17 (192.168.1.17) port 64962
* Connected to 192.168.1.17 (192.168.1.17) port 21 (#0)
> TYPE I
< 200 Switching to Binary mode.
> STOR filename
< 550 Permission denied.
* Failed FTP upload: 550
```

According curl is not permission. Im sure that persmission are set correct, even try on 777. When i using ftp client like filezilla uploading is ok. Please help

Answer (score 0):

> < 550 Permission denied.

This is the message from the FTP server which does not allow you to write to the root `/`. Given the URL you gave your intention was not to write to `/` but to `/home`. Maybe it helps if you remove the duplicate slash from your URL, i.e.

```
instead of   ftp://192.168.1.17//home/
use          ftp://192.168.1.17/home/
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I forgot to close files after `upload(local, remote)`.

Try this instead.